# What is the fastest way to map unique values from one pandas dataframe to another?

Tags: python, pandas, function, mapping, apply

I am trying to map the unique values from a column in one dataframe (`df1`) to a new column in another (`match_df`) based on the values in a list in a column of `match_df`.

The data:

- `df1` has 10 million rows and the columns: `['ID', 'match1', 'match2']`
- `match_df` has 10000 rows and is a dataframe grouped on 'match1' to give unique values and counts of 'match2' and 'id'. It has the columns: `['match1', 'match2_unique', 'match2_count', 'ID_unique', 'ID_count']`

I want to create a list in a new column, `match_df['match2_ids']`, for all IDs that are linked to 'match2' in `df1`.

The following does the job but takes over an hour to run and `match_df` is a subset from what could be a 6 million row dataframe. Ultimately, I would like to be able to perform the function on the full 6 million but computational power will not allow that at the moment..

```
def map_IDs(x):
    return list(df1[df1['match2'].isin(list(x))].ID.unique())

match_df['match2_ids'] = match_df['match2'].apply(lambda x: map_IDs(x))
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

edit: example added

```
example = {
    'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    'match1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'd'],
    'match2': ['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b1', 'c1', 'c1', 'c1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1']
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(example)
match_df = df1.groupby(['match1']).agg({
     'match2': ['unique', 'nunique'],
     'ID': ['unique', 'count']
}).reset_index()
match_df.columns = match_df.columns.map(''.join)
```

mid-way grouped dataframe:

```
|match1|match2unique|match2nunique|IDunique    |IDcount|
|:-----|:-----------|:-----------:|:-----------|:-----:|
| 'a'  |['a1', 'a2']|  2          |[1, 2, 8, 9]|   4   |
| 'b'  |['b1']      |  1          |[3, 4]      |   2   |
| 'c'  |['c1']      |  1          |[5, 6, 7]   |   3   |
| 'd'  |['a1']      |  1          |[10]        |   1   |
```

mapping function:

```
match_df_final['match2_IDs'] = match_df.match2unique.apply(lambda x:
    list(df1[df1['match2'].isin(list(x))].ID.unique())
)
```

final solution:

```
|match1|match2unique|match2nunique|IDunique    |IDcount|match2_IDs      |
|:-----|:-----------|:-----------:|:-----------|:-----:|:--------------:|
| 'a'  |['a1', 'a2']|  2          |[1, 2, 8, 9]|   4   |[1, 2, 8, 9, 10]|
| 'b'  |['b1']      |  1          |[3, 4]      |   2   |[3, 4]          |
| 'c'  |['c1']      |  1          |[5, 6, 7]   |   3   |[5, 6, 7]       |
| 'd'  |['a1']      |  1          |[10]        |   1   |[1, 8, 9, 10]   |
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear – could you provide a small, reproducible example of what the data looks like? Also, I'm not sure what your broader goal is, but it seems like maybe `merge` would be a better solution (building a list column in pandas is generally a sign of using the data structures in a suboptimal way).

Comment: @C.Braun, thanks for your reply. I've added some dummy data to show what I'm trying to do. I realise that holding a list in a column isn't ideal but this was supposed to be a quick exercise to compare the efficacy of one matching pattern against another. I have thought about using `df.groupby(['match1','match2']).agg(...)` but I think this would complicate matters when it comes to the comparison stats when this is finished.